# Zend-framework Error while trying ZF create project

Tags: zend-framework

when i was trying ZF create project test. I got this error message.
Pls help me to correct this.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance() in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64

Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance() in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64
```

Answer (score 0):

from [PHP Unit Installation instructions](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/installation.html) :

> PHP_CodeCoverage, the library that is used by PHPUnit 3.5 to collect
>   and process code coverage information, depends on Xdebug 2.0.5 (or
>   later) but Xdebug 2.1.2 (or later) is highly recommended.

So you need to install it using PEAR , so either install PEAR or update your existing pear installation and do these commands to install PHP_CodeCoverage

```
pear config-set auto_discover 1
pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHP_CodeCoverage
```